# jQuery AJAX URL getting folder prepended from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I am trying to make a jQuery AJAX call from an iframe. I can't put my code here, but I will try to create a similar example.

My actual page is served from `localhost:3000/dev-file-import`. The page contains the code to render an iframe like the below

```html
<iframe id="fileimport"
  src="../../fileimport/index.html?${encodeURI(dataToIframe()}"
  title="fileimport"
  width="100%"
  height={600}
  frameBorder="0">
```

The index.html contains an AJAX call which should be like  `https://localhost:3000/mock/../../...` but when the AJAX call is happening from the iframe it's prepending the iframe path as well, ie. `https://localhost:3000/**fileimport**/mock/...`

How can I stop the `fileimport` getting prepended when the AJAX call happens?

FYI: My parent application is in React, and the iframe code is in jQuery.
Please find the folder structure below 
My folder structure
[image: Jquery code laoding as result of iframe]

iframe code from public
[image: Iframe is included from fileimport.tsx]

Comment: Sounds like you just need another `../` in the path in order to go up an extra directory

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I had tried that, it's not rendering relatively, even though I alter  the relative path and make the iframe src as  src="../fileimport/index.html?${encodeURI(dataToIframe()}", it's still rendering. I don't know why it's treating as absolute path